# How to properly use (0 : 0) in verbs

Tags: j

I am trying to define the following entity

```
  x =: fn 
text 
...
)
NB. x is a noun
```

Notice that no other argument except the text is given to `fn`. If I understand correctly `fn` could be only a verb. I found a [package](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Phrases/Definitions) which archives similar results but `fn` there is an adverb. I tried to use 0 : 0 in an verb (monad and dyad) but got syntax error. What am I doing wrong ? Why the 0 : 0 trick can be used only in adverbs ?

Comment: If you want `x` to get the output of `fn`  then `x =: fn (0 : 0)` . If you want `x` to be a text then `x =: 0 : 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0 : 0` creates a noun based on the subsequent lines until a line containing only a `)` is reached.

if we use the verb  `;:`  (Words - which boxes the j sentence argument into words) as fn, then this is what we get from the assignment.

```
   a=: ;: (0 : 0)
here
we
go
)
   a
+----+-+--+-+--+-+
|here| |we| |go| |
+----+-+--+-+--+-+

   (<LF)= each a
+-------+-+---+-+---+-+
|0 0 0 0|1|0 0|1|0 0|1|
+-------+-+---+-+---+-+
```

The last part shows us that the blanks in the boxes are the linefeeds between lines.

Hope this helps

Cheers, bob